# Access some fields from another module as many2one fields

Tags: xml, python-2.7, odoo-10

I have some fields  in a module which i want to access as many2one fields in my module but fails to access the fields.

Here is my code:-

Code:-

```
class location_rental(models.Model):
   _name = "location.rental"


   location_id = fields.Char('Location_id', required=True)
   location_name = fields.Char("Location Name")
   row = fields.Char("Row")
   column = fields.Char("Column")
   level = fields.Char("Level")
```

Code:-

```
class rental_pet(models.Model):
    _name = 'rental.pet'


   location_id = fields.Many2one('location.rental.location_id', string="Location Id")
   row = fields.Many2one("location.rental.row", string="Row")
```

I am accessing many2one fields as shown in above code but it shows an error. May I get some help?

Answer (score 0):

```
class rental_pet(models.Model):
    _name = 'rental.pet'

   location_rental_id = fields.Many2one('location.rental',string="location_rental")
   location_id = fields.Char(related='location_rental_id.location_id',string="Location Id")
   row = fields.Char(related='location_rental_id.row', string="Row")
```

Comment: You can use this code :**row = fields.Many2one('location.rental',related='row', string="Row")** but row most be unique in location.rental .

Comment: It shows an error "Runtime Error: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object" while applying the code.

Comment: Is there any solution for that?